# DataStax/Tinkerpop - Ability to remove a property

Tags: datastax, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, datastax-startup

I am looking a way to remove a [propertyKey](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/reference/schema/refPropKey.html) in the schema. The documentation [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/reference/refSchemaAPI.html) explains how to add properties but no information about the removal. Does that mean that it is not possible?

Since DataStax relies on Cassandra that supports table altering I guess there is some way to achieve that, otherwise how to deal with dynamic schemas where properties can be added or removed?

**Edit**: For more clarity I want to remove the property both in the schema and in the data. Exactly like the `ALTER DROP` in SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP COLUMN column_name
```

Answer (score 1):

The DSE Graph reference for dropping data, schema or graphs is: http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/dropSchemaDataStudio.html

Comment: I am looking to remove a single propertyKey specifically. The link you provided does not explain how to do that.

Comment: The docs above contain the following note, if you need to modify the schema then you need to run schema.clear() and regenerate the schema.  "Important: Currently, certain schema elements such as a vertex label cannot be individually modified or removed. If a change to the schema is necessary, drop the whole schema as detailed above and recreate."

Answer (score 0):

As DSE Graph is built on the standards of TinkerPop, you can also leverage the TinkerPop 3 API references here - http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_tinkerpop3.

For this item, i believe you are looking for .drop().  http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#drop-step

From the above link, if you want to remove a property, do this: `.properties("X").drop()`

Comment: drop() allows to remove the data but does touch to the schema, which is what I need